# Add characters to Python unicode strip?

Tags: python, regex, text, unicode

I want to remove trailing whitespace and some other characters from strip. Here goes example input/output(tabs and newlines explicitly marked):

```
Input:
"\t [[  dwarf ]]]   \n"

Output:
"dwarf"
```

Now I could theoretically solve my problem like this, :

```
x = x.strip().strip("[]").strip().strip("[]")
```

This should exhaust every combination that can happen in my database; however, I still would need to change the code if we had more levels of brackets and whitespace. I could solve this generically with loops, but it would be just as ugly and inefficient. Is there a better way, or a way to tell strip not to use whole string, but rather the characters I provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a regex version with UNICODE support.

```
>>> import re
>>> st = "\t [[  dwarf ]]]   \n"
>>> re.sub(r"\s*\[|\]\s*", "", st, flags=re.UNICODE).strip()
'dwarf'
```

Little bit elegant regex than the previous one(use `ur` to handle UNICODE regex patterns):

```
>>> re.sub(ur"[ \s*[\] ]+", "", st, flags=re.UNICODE).strip()
```

Comment: Looks good to me when testing in REPL. I would however replace `r` with `ur`, just for the sake of people dealing with unicode regexes - I'm new to Python and I often find myself fighting with its regexes only to discover I forgot to put 'u' in front of it. Same for empty string.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to call `str.strip` once:

```
In [6]: import string

In [7]: "\t [[  dwarf ]]]   \n".strip("[]" + string.whitespace)
Out[7]: 'dwarf'
```

[`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) is a string containing all (ascii) whitespace characters. `S.strip("[]" + string.whitespace)` will strip all combinations of `[`, `]` and whitespace characters.

Comment: Great. What about `unicode`? Is there `unicode.whitespace`?

Comment: @MatthewRock: I'm not qualified to comment on Python 2, sorry. As far as I know, there's no `unicode.whitespace` or equivalent.

Comment: @MatthewRock can you check my answer if that helps.?